# Image as button for Selectmenu jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use an image as button for the jQuery selectmenu widget?

I tried this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3><img src="images/newiconoptions.png" style="float:right;"/></h3>
<p>I'm the collapsible content</p>
</div>
```

But then I get a button with the image in it, I just want to use the image as button.

Thanks.

Comment: check the final answer with all methods through that you can use an image as a button or make the image clickable.

Comment: check new answer for on image click select menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your further question you can follow this fiddle that i created for select menu when you click on an image :

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/WYm4H/13/]
```

This function you can write for calling select menu on image click:

```
$('.image').click(function() {
$('.select').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. Following should be the methods to do it:-

(1). As mentioned in the jQuery image-selector reference.

http://api.jquery.com/image-selector/

OR

(2).

```
<input type="image" src="your image source" alt="{alternate text}" />
```

OR

(3).  This makes image clickable:

```
 <div data-role="collapsible">
<h3><img src="images/newiconoptions.png" id="image"style="float:right;"/>   </h3>
<p>I'm the collapsible content</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#image').click(function(){
      // this makes image clickable

 });
```

OR

(4). you can also apply the proper css to the image as:

```
#image{
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: and how can I use the image click function to open a select menu under it? thanks

Comment: please post your select menu so that i can create a jsfiddle. and also if the answer is helpful and correct then please accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use image as select menu button in jquery one need to override jquery classes which jquery add while creating the select menu.

No need to change jquery .css file just override them (properties / attribite) using style attribute of the tag.

use following code to do this it worked for me ->

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div data-icon="none" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn" style="margin: 0px; text-align: inherit;">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../../images/image.png" style="">           
        <select id="selectMenuCls" data-native-menu="true" size="0" data-role="none">         
            <option value="" class="first">c</option>       
            <option value="" class="">c++</option>       
            <option value="" class="">java</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

please note that in select tag data-role="none" attribute is essential so that jquery will not apply it's custom classes to select menu